# DDD - Business decisions are based on database logic

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I am trying to follow DDD in the following pattern.

```
Controller-----DataContract----> Domain Layer (DDD)

Controller-----Domain Object---> Repository---Entity--->EntityFramework
```

As you see in the above diagram, the **domain layer** is independent to make business decisions, but in my case, most of the business decisions are taken on the fly. For example,

```
if(Account Number Associated?)
     Load CustomerDetails //A database call is needed
     ....
     .....
     if(Has customer another loan)
           .....
           .....
           Load other loan details //A database call is needed
           .....
           .....
           if(Was that repaid?)
               ....
               ....
               Load collateral details //A database call is needed
               .....
               .....
               Calculate collateral details and return.
           else
               Load other data //A database call is needed
      else
           Load other data //A database call is needed

else
     Load other data //A database call is needed
```

As you see the above example, the application is making a lot of business decisions on the fly by making database calls. Since **Domain Layer** should not depend on the **Repository Layer**, I don't know how to proceed.

I may use **Application service** for database calls, but then **Domain Layer** wouldn't have any logic in it. All the logic would go into the **Application Service**.

Please help me in this.

-Pandian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least three possible ways out

1) Design your repository to load the entire aggregate at once.  This approach gives the domain model all of the state that it may need right away, rather than trying to load the state on demand.

2) Run the queries in the app service, and pass the data to the domain model.  Ideally, you do this in advance (so that you are making a single call into the domain model), but when that doesn't make sense you have the domain model tell the app service what data is needed, and the app service finds that data and returns it.

3) Pass a repository into the domain model that allows it to read the data that it needs.  This is essentially the "domain service" pattern, but used to access a data store.

In this design, the domain model is defining the repository interface, and the application provides the implementation.  In other words, we're using the service provider pattern to keep the dependency arrows pointing the correct direction.

Comment: Hi @VoiceOfUnreason, Thanks for the help. The first two approaches are not possible in my case. Could you please point me to some github/code examples for this kind of "Domain Service"? Also, when you say "application provides the implementation" means "**application service** provides the implementation" right?

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason

In the third solution, the dependency points from domain model towards repository layer! What about that.

Answer (score 1):

@Pandiarajan Domain layer can contain domain models(entities, value objects), domain services and domain events.

From your code above, you can create a domain service that encapsulates all these domain logic and concepts that are not naturally modeled as value objects or entities. These domain service can take a repository that handles all the database calls.

Note also that if the data you need to return are for read-only or reporting purpose, you may want to look for CQRS as alternative. In CQRS, all these read-queries can bypass your domain layer in presenting data. CQRS will eliminate the need of transforming your data to a domain model.

Comment: Could you please help me by pointing some sample projects in github or somewhere?